# PDOException with Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, git, laravel, amazon-ec2

I just pushed to git my project and cloned it in my EC2 instance. Changed `.env` database configuration, cleared the cache and restarted apache2 but still get

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Why does it still gives me this error after changing the configuration in .env? This is how the .env file looks like:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=q8LzfpBKoFYv4i4zvobgYYdm2910zH0o

DB_HOST=blue*******.***********.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_DATABASE=cms
DB_USERNAME=free******
DB_PASSWORD=****************

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: Does an admin user exist with the password you have defined of your EC2 instance? You can also try `php artisan config:clear` to use the latest version of your configuration.

Comment: Actually I'm connected to a RDS instance. So in the `.env` file I set the db_host which is the RDS instance, the db_name, user and pass. And in the erorr it still shows my previous DB connection settings.

Comment: Use `php artisan config:clear` to clear the old DB connection settings - it will then use your new settings next time around.

Comment: As I said, did this but still the same error...God, never experienced such an annoying error

Comment: Did you allow your EC2 IP adress in your RDS security parameters?

Comment: Could you provide a copy of your .env file hiding the fields involved in your authentification?

Comment: @El_Matella Updated the question, check it out. About the security parameters - I have two projects running on this instance. The one with the exact same `.env` configuration runs fine, but the other project gives me this error

Comment: Do you have exactly the following lines involving the env variables in your config/database.php file: 'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

Comment: Well, in this file I have set the array elements so to be the same as in `.env` (set the db name to `cms`, the db host and so on)

Comment: @El_Matella You know what is the weirdest thing? When I removed the `.env` file and cleared all the db configuration in `config/database.php`, Laravel keeps getting this connection data from somewhere...

Comment: Well, I am sorry to ask you that, but are you sure that you are working on the right files? On your EC2 machine? Double check....

Comment: Yeah, I have only one EC2 instance and one RDS instance there can't be anything wrong here